# Extend Laravel 5 Response Facade

Tags: php, laravel, fatal-error, facade

I am getting a namespacing issue when trying to extend the Response facade in Laravel 5. I have created a new folder tree under the `app` directory called `Extensions\Facades`. In this folder I have a file called `AjaxResponse.php` which has the following contents:

```
<?php namespace App\Extensions\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class AjaxResponse extends Response{

    public static function send($code,$body,$http_code=200){

        parent::json( array(
                'status'=>(string)$code,
                'body' =>$body
            ) )->setStatusCode($http_code)->send();
        exit();

    }
}
```

I am registering this as a service provider in `config/app.php` like I understand I am supposed to:

```
providers=[
            //..normal stuff
            'App\Extensions\Facades\AjaxResponse',
]
```

And this is throwing the normal namespace error of class not found:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 150: 
Class 'App\Extensions\Facades\AjaxResponse' not found
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the class is not found?

Comment: Try with *use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;* (notice the backslash at the beginning). Anyway, a ServiceProvider should overwrite the register method, refer to Facades on Laravel docs.

Comment: The error is related to the class I have created not the class I have used. I dont think there is an issue with this. Also the `ProviderRepository.php` reference relates back to the inclusion of my new class in the `config\app.php` file I think

Comment: OK got you. I am wrong to try and load the extension as a service provider. Makes sense. I just need to be able to use this class. Doesnt matter what I try it still tells me the class cannot be found! Damned PHP namespaces they always give me a headache

Comment: This has nothing to do directly with your problem, but you might want to take a look at [Response Macros](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#response-macros)

Comment: Yeah I am actually using this approach and is a solid suggestion. For academic reasons would still like to figure this mo fo out

Comment: What do you have in **in ProviderRepository.php line 150**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to project root folder and in the terminal type

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Everything should be fine then. When you create a new folder, composer does not know about it, so it can not autoload files from it, even if they are `psr-4` namespaced.

**EDIT** Also you need to declare alias for your facade in `config/app.php` under aliases array, not the providers one:

```
 'AjaxResponse'   => 'App\Extensions\Facades\AjaxResponse',
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Still getting the f-in error but this is good stuff.