# Extend Laravel 5's Response Facade to include further helpers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I'm trying to allow an user to do something like `response()->yaml(['their content'])`, but I don't understand how I'd go on injecting my YAML method to the response() (ResponseFactory) facade.

Is there any guide that would explain on how to do this? Or maybe a quick description from someone? This is the first time I'm trying to build a package for Laravel and it will also be open source!

I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441182/extend-laravel-5-response-facade), but unfortunately I don't see its use case and I don't think it focuses on adding an additional method which would be called via `response()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can you use `Response Macros` to achieve your aim.

In the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider` (or in the package ServiceProvider) add the following:

```
Response::macro('yaml', function ($content) {
    return yaml_whatever($content); //Use your implementaion here
});
```

Now, you can use `return response()->yaml($content);`

Comment: Wow, but these functions **can't be autocompleted** in IDEs like phpStorm so I'll look for a solution where Response class get extended